# Implementing Custom Gates by using Qiskit Pulse in Qiskit 1.0.0

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

I'm using Qiskit 1.0.0.

I'm trying to define a custom gate from a certain wavefunction and insert it in a quantum circuit that I want to run and measure the counts.

The relevant code for the question is as follows:

```
backend = FakePerth()
custom_gate_ch1 = Gate('ch1', 1, [])
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)

with builder.build() as ch1_gate:
    builder.play(wave, DriveChannel(0))

backend.target.add_instruction(
    custom_gate_ch1,
    {(0,): InstructionProperties(calibration=ch1_gate)},
)

circ.append(custom_gate_ch1, [0])
circ.measure_all()
circ = passmanager.run(circ)

tqc = transpile(circ, backend, scheduling_method='asap')
counts = backend.run(tqc).result().get_counts()
```

With this code, I'm able to obtain the transpiled circuits correctly, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

`qiskit.providers.basic_provider.exceptions.BasicProviderError: 'basic_simulator encountered unrecognized operation "ch1"'`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you found a solution? I think that there is nothing wrong in particular with your code. Just the transition to Qiskit 1.0.x did not happen as smoothly as hoped and not all functionality was kept.

I am facing the same issue with a sub-circuit including parameters for BasicSimulator. I found the solution by decomposing the circuit with abstract gates/circuits into the basic gate set before sending it to the BasicSimulator. Maybe it helps you.

```
decomposed = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['cx', 'id', 'rz', 'sx', 'x'])
backend = BasicSimulator()
job_results = backend.run(decomposed, shots=1).result()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).